# How to 'delete' this linked list from memory?

Tags: c++

I've created class for building a linked list. The class declaration is as follows:

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:
      int data;
      LinkedList *next;
      static int count;

     public:
      LinkedList(void);
      ~LinkedList(void);

      int insert(int arg);
      int remove(int arg);
      bool find(int arg);
};
```

How can I make sure all nodes of this linked list are *deleted*? The destructor is made responsible for *deleting* just one node. I used to make linked list like this previously but never thought about clearing the memory.

Comment: If using smart pointers, you can continue with your old behaviour.

Comment: @DumbCoder As Mike pointed out below, you have to be careful with this.  A large list can lead to a stack overflow as you are effectively creating a recursive delete chain.

Comment: Not the answer, but I would reorganize the code a little bit. A "list" is comprised with "items", and this is how we humans think about them. Your current class `LinkedList` should be renamed `LinkedListItem`, and there should be another class that is the actual `LinkedList`. `count` member and all member functions should be moved to this new class, and `count` should not be static.

Comment: @Dialecticus; I agree. It's like creating a `struct` for representing a node and then implement a class using this structure. But I used the above approach as it's part of a very short program. I'd definitely keep your point in mind when implementing a linked list for a comparatively larger program.

Comment: @HarshilSharma This is not a good approach IMO. You're perpetuating bad habits.

Comment: @Spook; yeah, I realized that reading the comments on Mike Seymour's answer. I'll change it to a `listItem` and `list` way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naive implementation

```
~LinkedList() {delete next;}
```

will do the right thing - `delete` will call the destructor on the next element, which will delete the one following it, and so on, to delete the whole list.

However, this means that the destructors are called recursively, so that deleting a very long list could cause a stack overflow. Iteration might be better:

```
~LinkedList() {
    while (LinkedList * head = next) {
        next = head->next;
        head->next = nullptr;
        delete head;
    }
}
```

As noted in the comments, it might be more appropriate to have separate `List` and `Node` classes, with `List` responsible for memory management, and `Node` a simple aggregate containing the data and the link. Then there's less scope for error in the destructor, as it doesn't need to nullify any pointers to prevent recursion:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node * next;
};

struct List {
    Node * head;

    ~List() {
        while (Node * victim = head) {
            head = victim->next;
            delete victim;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This breaks single responsibility rule, IMO.

Comment: @Spook: Is that more important than robustness against stack overflow?

Comment: @Spook That is a matter of perspective.  If you think it is the list's responsibility to maintain *just* the first node, then you are correct.  If you think it is the list's responsibility to maintain the whole list, you are incorrect.  Since a "list" should (semantically) maintain the whole list, this does not break the single responsibility rule.

Comment: @MikeSeymour First of all, isn't the second solution recursive as well?

Comment: @Spook Not at all.  It is iterating the list with a single call stack.

Comment: @ZacHowland Ok, but `delete head` calls again `~LinkedList()`, which calls `delete head` which calls... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Spook: I've fixed the code so that `delete head` just deletes a single node (i.e. it recurses once, not all the way along the list) - my first attempt did indeed have an error.

Comment: @ZacHowland Actually, I believe, that the presented class breaks the SRR in the beginning. It contains "find" and "count", which belongs to class *managing* the actual linked list and - in the same time - "next", which implies, that this class is the list's item as well.

Comment: @Spook Ah, sorry, with this code, yes you are correct.  I was looking at it and thinking it was a typical linked list implementation with a `LinkedListNode`.  But with Mike's edit, it won't be recursive as he is making the next pointer null before deleting it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, be sure to NULL out head's next pointer or you'll have both destructors deleting the next node and a double-delete, which is undefined behavior and will probably crash your process.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: Indeed, I've just fixed that.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson This is very weird usage of the class dtor to destroy a structure, which this class is a part of. This will surely result in problems in the future (forget to NULL the next to unintentionally destroy the rest of list). Destruction of the list should be placed in separate entity (function or method of class, which *manages* the list). It's a nice language trick, but IMO totally unpractical.

Comment: @Spook: I've added a brief diversion on how to better separate responsibilities.

Comment: One additional question: I thought of pointing to each node in LinkedList from a `std::vector` to accelerate indexed lookups. What would you say about this?

Comment: @HarshilSharma: I'd say that you'd almost certainly be better off just using a vector.

Comment: @Spook, I don't disagree.  I personally would have let the recursive version stand, or (if I was really worried about stack overrunning) moved clean-up to a dedicated owner class.  I was merely pointing out an obvious and fatal flaw with the solution as posted (at the time).

Comment: As a side note, there's a reasonable chance the recursive version wouldn't have a stack overrunning problem, if the compiler can recognize the destruction as tail-end recursion and do an optimized tail call.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson: It's not a tail call; the memory has to be deallocated afterwards.